# "Untitled window" icons when using Android Studio

Tags: unity, android-studio

While using Android Studio on 12.04.3, I keep getting a lot of untitled window icons in the left bar:

[image]

I can't click or close them (the only options are "keep in launcher" or "close", which does nothing).

Is there any way I can fix this?

#### Edit

Some additional info:

- This also happens in 13.10, but those icons appear and dissapear almost instantly.
- It seems to be caused by the tooltips that appear in the IDE (ex: method signature).
- This happens while using the launcher created by Android Studio or launching directly in the terminal.

Comment: How are you running AS?

Comment: I use the launcher created by Android Studio.

Comment: Maybe try and reinstall Unity? it's a long stretch but who knows...

Comment: have you tried run through terminal? `path-to-androidstudio/bin/studio.sh`

Comment: @riccivr Yes I get the same behavior.

Comment: when you open android-studio try reload unity with this `alt+f2` and type `unity` and tell me what happens with the icons

Comment: Reloading Unity makes those icons go away. It's not a very good solution but will do the trick for now.

Comment: Please turn your comment in a answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is a temporary solution to this issue:
open android studios normally, and then press alt + f2 and type `unity`, you will see those icons dissapear.

Answer (score -2):

I would uninstall Unity, then reinstall Unity and reboot, then try it. If that doesn't work, then run `[sudo] path-to-androidstudio/bin/studio.sh` , and try it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Running it as [sudo] will give it more permissions, which lessens the chance of glitchs.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Running an IDE as root??? How can this possibly help? Also uninstalling/installing Unity would not remove Unity configuration...